# How do I make an image with Sinatra and haml?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm a Sinatra/Ruby n00b. How do I make Ruby recognize my own image paths?

In my haml file, I have this line:

```
  %img{:src => "/img/logo.png"}
```

But when I open the page I get a 404 error:

http://localhost:4567/img/logo.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Well, _did_ you put `logo.png` at that path?

Comment: Yes I did, the home directory has index.rb which is where that line of code in the question comes from, then in that same directory is img, and img has logo.png

Comment: It's likely that you didn't configure root of your app. Take a look here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The default folder Sinatra looks into for static assetes is the `public` folder.

In your projects root directory create a directory called `public`. Inside of that create your `img/logo.png` path.

```
my_sinatra_project/app.rb  # example of file where your sinatra routes are defined
my_sinatra_project/public/img/logo.png  # where to put your static assets
```